# can't enter random number into text field - getting overload error

Tags: random, textbox, karate

I have tried to enter a random number into a text field and receive the following error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: js failed:
>>>>
01: value('locator', randomNumber)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (value) on com.intuit.karate.driver.chrome.Chrome@1ad47760 failed due to: no applicable overload found (overloads: [Method[public com.intuit.karate.driver.Element com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.value(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)], Method[public java.lang.String com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.value(java.lang.String)]], arguments: [#taxid (String), DynamicObject<JSFunction>@6855d081 (Unbound)])
```

when I use value('locator', randomNumber) and

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: js failed:
>>>>
01: input('locator', randomNumber)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (input) on com.intuit.karate.driver.chrome.Chrome@29bbeb45 failed due to: no applicable overload found (overloads: [Method[public com.intuit.karate.driver.Element com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.input(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)], Method[public default com.intuit.karate.driver.Element com.intuit.karate.driver.Driver.input(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[])], Method[public default com.intuit.karate.driver.Element com.intuit.karate.driver.Driver.input(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[],int)], Method[public default com.intuit.karate.driver.Element com.intuit.karate.driver.Driver.input(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int)]], arguments: [#taxid (String), DynamicObject<JSFunction>@15193ade (Unbound)])
```

when I use input('locator', randomNumber). I have tried to generate the random number two different ways (not simultaneously):

1. ```
   * def randomNumber = function(max){ return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) }
   ```
2. ```
   * def randomNumber = function(){ var temp = ''; karate.repeat( 9, function() { temp += Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) } ); return temp; }
   ```

For 1. above, I use randomNumber(100000000) to generate a 9-digit random number which I pass into the value() and input methods().
The above methods are properly generating the random number, but the problem occurs when entering the text into the textbox. Any help, feedback, suggestions?

Comment: sorry no idea. follow this process (exactly as described) if you can: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas  can I use script('locator', "_.value = 'value' ") where the value is a parameter? You had suggested this option to clear the textbox in another thread, but can I use this to enter a random number? If so, how do I use a parameter instead of a hard-coded value?

Comment: you can - but you need to understand this section of the docs first. please read it carefully: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#karate-vs-the-browser